# MFMailcomposer localize To: Cc/Bcc: and Subject: fields

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, localization, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I there a way to localize To:, Cc/Bcc: and Subject: titles in MFMailcomposerController? Or customize them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MFMailcomposer is already localised by apple and those fields should automatically change depending on the current language settings of the device. (CC/Bcc won't though I think). You can't customise them as far as I'm aware though.

Comment: I invoke it when my iphone is set on another language and i still see it in english. What can be the problem? Thanks

Comment: Is your app localized? Apple's own controls always use the language of the current app, not that of the device.

Comment: Actually I don't need it localized, but i assume, that i need some minimum implemented just in order to see the mail fields localized.
What is that required minimum for application to be considered localized? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I didn't spell right the localization name, that's was all my problem.
MFMailComposer indeed behaves according to localization